# Digital signature in a group chat scenario?

Tags: encryption, rsa, signature

I understand that RSA is great for 1-to-1 digital signature. In the group chat of N people, other than storing and maintaining N public keys, is there a simpler way of authenticating each and everyone in the room?  Perhaps with just one public key per client?

Comment: Do you want to be able to say 'this message came from Bob', or are you content with 'this message came from someone in the group (but I have no idea which group member)'?

Comment: @poncho I want to be able to say "this message came from bob"

Comment: No. Each public key maps to exactly one entity, how should you be able to say "this was a typical Bob". So less than n public keys for a n-person group chat isn't possible.